# BTCCTL: How to use the extended RPC commands?

Tags: btcd

I have a BTCD simnet set up locally on a couple machines. Now, I am looking to use the generatetoaddress RPC in btcctl to fund a couple of different wallets.

However, btcctl throws a "-32601: Method not found" error. In the repository it seems this function is part of some "extensions" (?)

I'd like to know if there is a way to enable this service in my BTCD setup.